# actionPerformed has empty logic

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

I have a screen which has list. By right click, I can open a small pop up and add new records to the that list by choosing some record and clicking OK button from pop up.

OK button which is on pop up has an action listener like below:

```
okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

And that is all the `actionPerformed` method does and I do not understand how this method is adding new record to the list on main window. There should be another part of code which is connected to this part but I do not know what is that. Do you have any idea what I do not see on that logic?

Comment: How did you add the original records to the list? Do it the same way. For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: actually it is added from the same pop up.

Comment: Where is the MCVE?

Comment: Without the code it's nearly impossible to answer but if your popup is a `JOptionPane` and you use a `show...` function then the selected 'option' is return. So you can know which button was clicked.

Answer (score 2):

The ActionListener is not empty and in fact it is changing the state of the window that holds the JButton, making it no longer visible.

No one can say with 100% confidence what logic is being used here since you've yet to show enough code for that, but our guess is that this button is being held within a *modal* JDialog -- a window that freezes code flow in the calling code once the dialog window is visible, and (here's the key) that *releases the block* on code flow once this dialog is no longer visible. So in this situation, making the dialog no longer visible will allow the calling code, the code that initially told the dialog to display itself, to resume flow of its logic. Presumably in the subsequent code, it will query the dialog for data that was entered, and extract it, again the details of which are in code not yet shown to us.